# oData.read() method triggering uncaught error

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

I am using SAP UI5, and was trying to fetch some data from a public odata [service](http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW).

I making the call in the following code snippet.

```
matched:function(oEvent){
if(!sap.ui.getCore().getModel("emp"))
    {
    var url = this.getOwnerComponent().getMetadata().getConfig().service.url
    console.log("url")
    console.log(url)
    var oData = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(url,true)

    oData.read("/People?top=5",{
        async:true,
        success:function(oData,response){
        var eModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        eModel.setData(oData);
        sap.ui.getCore().setModel("emp", eModel)

    }
```

And I have configured the service url in Component.js like so..

```
        config : {
        resourceBundle : "i18n/messageBundle.properties",
        service:{
            url:"http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW"
        }
```

As soon as the oData.read() method is called an uncaught error is thrown.. from js files in resources folder.

[image: Error log]

I checked the network tab in the browser , each time  oData.read() is called I see 4 calls being made
1.http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(d1goo34fnpbdpleuuykeha2r))/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata
2.http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(pgzb5mtb0yp5ytw25xrdfcxl))/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata
3.http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People?top=5
4.http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(zobeyavqtqtykfyyj1m4jqrt))/TripPinServiceRW/People?top=5

Except for the third all others return status 200 , the third one returns status 302.

The last request does return data , but the query doesn't work, instead of top 5 all the records are being fetched.

I would like to know if I am doing anything wrong , any sort of help is appreciated.TIA.

FYI the version for UI5 is 1.34.9

Also I had tested the public service using postman , it was working fine.

Comment: I am guessing based on the URL that the OData service you are using is OData V4, therefore you have to use the v4 ODataModel which should be available in the next version of SAPUI5.

Comment: @hirse thank you for the input.

Comment: @hirse could you suggest any sample odata service with version 2.0 so that i can confirm this?

Comment: I guess you can always go with the Northwind demo:
http://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata

Answer (score 0):

1. As for the OData version mismatch mentioned in the comments: You can try to include the request header `OData-MaxVersion`. If the service can provide a response compliant with that version, it will.
2. For the `top` not working: Please note that according to the [OData Spec V2](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/) the query option is named `$top`, not just `top`.

So just try:

```
var oData = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(url,true)
oData.setHeaders({
  "OData-MaxVersion": "2.0"
});

oData.read("/People?$top=5", {
   async:true,
   success:function(oData,response) {
      // ...
   }
 }
```